# Is it possible to set a start value for BigAutoFields?

Tags: python, peewee

Is it possible to specify a start value for `BigAutoField` types? if not, how can I make the start value to be e.g. 99?

```
from peewee import *

class MyModel
    id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True, start_value=99)
    # ... other attributes
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably is better to set this in the database rather than directly in the model field: `ALTER SEQUENCE <sequence_name> RESTART WITH <number>;`

Take a look here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-altersequence.html

Anyway, if you want this instruction to be part of the migrations of your app, you can:

1. Create an empty migration; `./manage.py makemigrations --empty <appname>`
2. edit the created migration file to include:

```
    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('ALTER SEQUENCE <sequence_name> RESTART WITH <number>;')
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am targeting two different databases: SQLite and Postgres.

Comment: Sqlite does not support sequences, and these numbers are created by the database (hence, Auto-field). For Sqlite you would probably want, instead, to use their special AUTOINCREMENT functionality and just fill the first X rows then delete them.